# ec2 linux performance in bash scripts of using $PATH vs /FULL/NAME vs ALIAS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-ec2

I am considering the speed/memory cost of scaling a large number of small bash scripts. The permutations of scripts calling each other will be quite large, <=5000 scripts.

Is there a benchmark or way of profiling best performance for using a particular method to call each script, say

1. searching $PATH (could be many deep directories needing to be added to $PATH
2. using MYFILE=/full/directory/path/file.sh in a number of config files
3. Using a large number of alias commands to store the more heavily used scripts

The target system will be a scaling cluster of m8.xl type ec2 instances that are general compute optimized with standard ssd i/o.

The reason for using this method is the development of the scripts will be produced by several teams and the only common document for reference is a basic db with function=myfile -p param, return=x, etc. so if a developer needs a function or script they would call the script name and one of the methods above would point to the actual script.

**UPDATE**
To clarify, the speed of launching the script is not that important if it is only marginally faster to use a method. The concern is the weight of script names being housed in memory having a detrimental effect on the overall performance.
Several hundred or thousand scripts may be spawned in a burst over a few seconds, so the peak load is a concern factor.

Thx
Art

Comment: The overhead will be in running the processes, not finding the scripts to run.  Use whichever seems easiest.  Absolute names will be marginally fastest, but they could easily be least flexible — when scripts move, you have to edit things.  Have you considered making the scripts into (shell) functions?  Will you have a single process launching the myriad scriptlets (functions) or will there be many processes each launching just one or two?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler processes will be spawned individually and possibly many hundreds run per second. Not complex, just many. I have updated the question to reflect your input.

Comment: How big are the scripts? A few kilobytes each?  If you have 5,000 scripts and each is about 5 KiB of code, then they only occupy about 25 MiB in caches etc — which is tiny.  So, the memory use for the stored scripts shouldn't be a direct concern, but the size of the shell might be. Do the scripts do the work in shell notation, or do the scripts themselves run other programs to get the 'real work' done?  Are they used in pipelines?  Do they themselves use pipelines?  The bursty launching will probably be the biggest problem, but it sounds as if you can't easily avoid launching many processes.

Comment: Are you using Bash?  Could you consider a smaller, lighter-weight shell such as Dash instead?  Have you made sure your Bash processes have the minimum of work to do when started non-interactively (appropriate profile and `.bashrc` files, etc)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes the scripts will be small, each one only doing basic file searching and string replacement on static files, ie read in a file, string replace then save it. Each file will almost be a function to itself. So looks like any of the methods should be ok. We have a couple of methods we can use such as a script does a source. but we would prefer moving to an API approach of calling a script/function and returning an exit code. I will look into the DASH idea. Thx Art